# Take a stream of incoming strings in flink and put them into an array

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm sending `JSON` to a kafka topic and with flink i'm reading from that topic the json in order to make some operations on the stream.
i realized the pojo of the stream and some operations like keyby etc.
I mapped that pojo to another one with map operator.
this is the code:

```
DataStream<OutputPojo> finalobjectStream = integrityobjectStream
        // mappo l'input con un output che ha anche il campo count
        .map(new MapFunction<IntegrityPojo, OutputPojo>() {
            public OutputPojo map(IntegrityPojo input) throws Exception {
                OutputPojo output = new OutputPojo();
                output.severity = input.severity;
                output.file = input.file;
                output.agent_name = input.agent_name;
                output.comment = input.comment;
                output.hostname = input.hostname;
                output.logfile = input.logfile;
                output.Timestamp = input.Timestamp;
                output.count = 1;
                return output;
            }
        })
        // raggruppo per il campo comment
        .keyBy(((KeySelector<OutputPojo, String>) integrity -> integrity.comment))
        // definisco la finestra temporale
        .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)))
        // addiziono il campo count
        .sum("count")
        // filtero se count è maggiore di un certo valore
        .filter(new FilterFunction<OutputPojo>() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(OutputPojo integrity) throws Exception {
                return integrity.count > 3;
            }
        });
```

I need output.file field as an array of the incoming strings input.file.
How can i do this?

Comment: no one? i cannot find any solution

Answer (score 0):

May like this?

```
// map transformer in the new MapFunction
DataStream<List<String>> dataStream = inputStream.map(line-> {
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s:fields){
        output.add(s);
    }
    return output;
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation as well, not just code.

Comment: the inputs are all single strings, they have to be added inside an array called output